# Python script finish but gives [2]+ Killed

Tags: python

I'm running python script as:

```
python3 /home/ubuntu/...
```

The last line in the code is:

```
def getdata3(...)
    ...
    datarALL = []
    responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
    if responsedata.status_code == 200:  # 200 for successful call
        responsedata = responsedata.text
        jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
        if "results" in jsondata:
            if jsondata["results"]:
                datarALL.extend(jsondata["results"])
    print ("{1} page {0} finished".format(page,str(datetime.now())))
    return datarALL
def processData(...)
    ....
    result= []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_of_pages) as executor:
        futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata3, page, hed, data, apifolder,additional)) for page in pages]
        for data in as_completed(futh):
            result.extend(data.result())
    print ("Finished generateing data.")
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    processData(...)
    ...
    print ("done")
```

On console I see:

```
done
[2]+  Killed                  python3 /home/ubuntu/....
```

Screen:

[image]

Why my script is being killed after the last command?

I should note: the Killed does not appear in every run of the code which is why i'm having trouble isolating the problem.

Comment: We really need to see the rest of your code, to deliver an answer. So far we can only speculate.

Comment: Does your script start any threads that don't end before the main thread ends?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser My code is multi-threading but when I check on HTOP only the main process is left when at the end... threads are getting the data they finish before I even do the "google storage upload" I'll edit my question with more code

Comment: @JakobSachs added code

Comment: @SpoonMeiser added code